# Array becomes undefined after page reload

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I am working on Angular WebApi. I have a database response on localhost in JSON format.
When I run my application, I can see the array `oData`. But when I reload the page then `oData` becomes undefined.

How can I solve this?

Here is my code from the .ts file:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.mydataser.getDbData().subscribe(data => {
      this.oData = data;
    });
  }

 public importData() {
    console.log(this.oData)
 }
```

Here is my service:

```
  getDbData(): Observable<DataFactory[]> {
    return this.http.get<DataFactory[]>("https://localhost:44216/api/dbdata");
  }
```

P.S. I tried to use localstorage but it does not work.

Comment: Please provide the minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare data as an empty array; if you don't do it will be undefined until the API response is completed. If you want to know when the response is actually coming just use [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap). So If you want to call `importData()` after API response is received then call `this.importData()` method inside `subscribe` like

```
// declare as empty array
oData = [];
buttonEnabled = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mydataser.getDbData().pipe(
        tap(d => this.buttonEnabled = true)
    ).subscribe(data => {
        this.oData = data;
    });
}

importData(): void{
 console.log(this.o.Data);
}
```

In template:

```
<button [disabled]="!buttonEnabled">Import</button>
```

Comment: After reload the array is empty.

Comment: yes because at the time when you do `console.log(o.Data)` that time response has not yet been received through `getDbData()`

Comment: Call `importData()` method inside `subscribe`, So whenever API is completed you will get data inside `o.Data` and `o.Data` will have data in `importData` method

Comment: Thank you. That works but I want to get the oData only when I call the method importData() and not every time when the page is loaded. I have a button that calls the importData() and then make some changes on the oData. Is there any way to call importData() not in the ngOnInit()?

Comment: If you want to make some changes into `oData` the data should be loaded at `ngOninit`. then you can modify `oData` on button click

Comment: Correct me if im wrong.. You want to set `o.Data` from `this.mydataser.getDbData()` in `ngOninit` but you want to modify `o.Data` in `importData()` which is called on Button Click?

Comment: yes, right this.

Comment: Since your `importData()` is dependent on `o.Data` you need to wait to get response from `this.mydataser.getDbData()` before button click...You can keep button disabled until you get response

Comment: @john check updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is working! :) Thanks!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote, if it solved your issue